# Read csv file from /tmp folder in Lambda, filter it and upload it to s3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a file that I need to filter based on user login information, then upload the filtered file to s3.

Here is my code:

```
csv_file = csv.reader(open('/tmp/users.csv', "r"))
    for row in csv_file:
        if result > row[6]: #'result' is the date I'm measuring against column 6 of the csv

            with open('/tmp/filtered.csv', 'w') as g:
                wf = csv.writer(g)
                wf.writerow(['User', 'First', 'Last', 'Email', 'Local', 'Membership', 'Login'])
                wf.writerows(row)
                print (row)
            bucket.upload_file('/tmp/filtered.csv', key)
```

While the 'print (row)' line gives me this output:

[image]

The actual csv file uploaded to s3 looks like this:

[image]

The csv output that I'm getting in the file amounts to a single user. I would like to get all users found by the filtering in a properly formatted list. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: When I change the line from ‘wf.writerows(row)’ to ‘wf.writerow(row)’ the file is properly formatted, but it is still just one user(last one) out of the entire dataset.

Comment: then is like to split your csv based in a login value?

Comment: Possible typo: `w.writerow()` instead of `wf.writerow()`

Comment: Why are you using `wf.writerows(row)` instead of `wf.writerow(row)`? The `row` variable would only contain one line of information.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks John for the correction. It’s a typo from the posting, and I just fixed it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein My assumption was that ‘.writerows()’ would return one line per user. Now that you mention it, when I use ‘.writerow()’ I get the very last user properly formatted.

Comment: Are you wanting one output file uploaded to the S3 bucket per row in the input file? So, if the input file had 4 rows, you would have 4 output files in S3? Or are you just wanting a single output file?

Comment: I notice that you are always uploading to the same `key` (filename). That would explain why the file contains only the last row from the input file. If you are wanting to upload multiple output files, you will need to change the `key` (filename) for each file otherwise they simply overwrite each other.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The goal would be to upload a single file containing all users that fit the criteria (akin the picture showing the ‘print (row)’ output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say your issue is related to the fact that you are opening the output file *for every row*:

```
for row in csv_file:
    with open('/tmp/filtered.csv', 'w') as g:
        wf = csv.writer(g)
        ...
```

This means that the contents of the output file is being overwritten for every row.

Instead, open the output file and create the csv writer *before* looping through each row of the input file:

```py
with open('/tmp/filtered.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    wf = csv.writer(output_file)
    wf.writerow(['User', 'First', 'Last', 'Email', 'Local', 'Membership', 'Login'])

    csv_file = csv.reader(open('/tmp/users.csv', "r"))
    for row in csv_file:
        if result > row[6]:
            wf.writerow(row)

bucket.upload_file('/tmp/filtered.csv', key)
```

This way, only one output file will be created.

Comment: Ah, that was it! I tend to be dyslexic when it comes down to lambda functions. Thanks a lot for the reply!